# Grails 5.0.1 - How to getting the domain transient properties

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, scaffolding, transient

How to getting the grails domain transient properties?
I need a class like org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernatePersistentEntity but that give all the properties of the domain - not only the persistenty properties.
My intent is to customize the project's scaffolding to render transient domain fields.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you wanting properties that are marked with the `transient` keyword or are you wanting properties included in the `static transients = [...]` property in a domain class?

Comment: Both. I want the properties included in the static transients (for example: confirm password field) and others. Going further: suppose we need to scour everything in the domain class - not only the persistent properties, what to do? Do you agree that with this knowledge our scaffolding becomes much more powerful? Thanks Jeff!